# Installing a Haskell package from Hackage through Cabal gets stuck at dependency resolution

Tags: haskell, ghc, cabal, hackage, cabal-install

Here is the output from verbose mode.  I know this used to work for me before but now this happens.  I've tried it with other packages and got the same result.

```
$ sudo cabal install test-framework-quickcheck2 -v
/usr/local/bin/ghc --numeric-version
looking for package tool: ghc-pkg near compiler in /usr/local/bin
found package tool in /usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg
/usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg --version
/usr/bin/gcc -dumpversion
/usr/local/bin/ghc -c /tmp/412.c -o /tmp/412.o
/usr/bin/ld -x -r /tmp/412.o -o /tmp/413.o
/usr/local/bin/ghc --supported-languages
Reading installed packages...
/usr/local/bin/ghc-pkg list
Reading available packages...
Resolving dependencies...
```

At this point, the program starts to eat up virtual memory, locking up the system and eventually prompting the OS to warn me of dwindling disk space.

Here's my environment.  I'm also on Mac OS X 10.4.11.

```
$ ghc --version  
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 6.8.2
$ ghc-pkg list -V
GHC package manager version 6.8.2
$ cabal --version
cabal-install version 0.5.9
using version 1.5.3 of the Cabal library
```

Comment: ghc 6.8.2 is rather old, and Cabal 1.5.3 is also pretty old. I would suspect such bugs are not present in GHC 6.12.{1,3} and Cabal 1.8. Perhaps you can upgrade to the Haskell Platform stable version? http://haskell.org/platform

Comment: I would have loved to except that my OS is also really old and there seems to be no easy way to do it for my OS.

Comment: I can confirm that this package works fine with the current stable releases of Cabal and GHC. You'll need to upgrade.

Comment: Note also that you are using a development version of both Cabal and cabal-install. Odd versions are dev versions, even versions are releases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution in this case is to **upgrade** to a more recent cabal-install/Cabal pair.
The current standard (to be part of the 2010.2 Haskell Platform) is:

- Caba1 1.8.0.6
- cabal-install 0.8.2

with GHC 6.12.3.